# Load Openssl provider shared object

Tags: openssl, shared-libraries

I'm failing to programmatically load a third party provider shared object.
Using the OpenSSL config file is not an option in my case.

```
OSSL_PROVIDER *MyProvider;
MyProvider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL, "/path/to/provider.so");
```

I also tried "OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path" and different combinations but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - what actually happens? Do you get a NULL result from your `OSSL_PROVIDER_load()` call? Try printing the error stack from OpenSSL to see if you can get more diagnostic info, `ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);`. Also try running your app through strace to see if you can see it attempting to load the .so and if it gives you any hint as to what the problem is. Typically you would not give "/path/to/provider.so" in the OSSL_PROVIDER_load() call. Just the name of the provider (no path, no .so suffix). Set `OPENSSL_MODULES` environment variable to the directory for the .so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to programmatically load a third-party provider shared object and cannot use OpenSSL's config file, there are a few other options.

Specify the provider using environment variables: Some third-party providers allow you to specify the path to their shared object using an environment variable. For example, if you are using the BoringSSL provider, you can set the **"OPENSSL_ENGINES"** environment variable to the path of the shared object.

Load the provider using the **"dlopen"** function: You can use the **"dlopen"** function to load the shared object at runtime. This allows you to specify the path to the shared object programmatically. For example, you can use the following code to load the BoringSSL provider:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
void* handle = dlopen("/path/to/boringssl.so", RTLD_NOW);
if (!handle) {
    // handle error
}
```

Once you have loaded the shared object, you can use the ENGINE_by_id function to load the provider.